# Confusion about DataOutputStream

Tags: java, dataoutputstream, inputstreamreader

I wrote the code below to familiarise myself with DataOutputStream. I suppose there would be some kind of `11010111` binary in the file where I output the data, instead, there are just some readable strings. My question is: shouldn't there be binary data in the file while DataOutputStream is used to output data?

Code:

```
FileOutputStream fos = null;
try {
    fos = new FileOutputStream("myData.dat");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("File Not Found!!");
    System.exit(-1);
}
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(fos));
try {
    dos.writeChars("HELLO WORLD!!!\n");
    dos.writeChars("HELLO PRETTIES!!!\n");
    dos.writeChars("HELLO KITTY!!!");
    dos.flush();
    dos.close();
    fos.close();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
FileInputStream fis = null;
try {
    fis = new FileInputStream("myData.dat");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("File Not Found!!");
    System.exit(-1);
}
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        new DataInputStream(fis)));
String s;
try {
    while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    br.close();
    fis.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: You're writing text to a file, and then you're surprised to find text in that file? What exactly did you think was going to happen?

Comment: @MikeBaranczak I think he wants to write chars in file which should be represented as binary format of each character

Comment: @BhavikShah That's exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All data in a computer is binary. Some binary data *may* be readable text, and this is what happens in your case.

The `writeChars` method writes each `char` of the String as two bytes. If you opened the file in a hex viewer you'd see that there's a NUL (`00`) byte before the ASCII code of each letter. When you open the file in a text editor, it interpretes the bytes in the file as text, because that's what text editors do: read a bunch of (binary) data and show it to you as text.

How the editor does this depends on the editor. Either it skips the NUL bytes and shows only the readable bytes, or interpretes the bytes as text encoded in UTF-16LE.

Comment: I get it. Thanks. Another question: I've been told that Binary I/O is much faster and more efficient than text I/O. So here, would that be more efficient when I use `DataOutputStream` rather than `FileWriter`-wrapping `PrintWriter`? Would that be even more efficient if I use `writeBytes` method instead of `writeChars`?

Comment: All I/O is "binary." The people who told you that may have meant that binary *file formats* are faster and more efficient. For example a `int` would be stored as the 4 bytes needed to store its 32 bits, instead of converting to a text string that represents a decimal number and occupies a variable number of bytes.

Comment: As to the question which of the alternatives would be faster, it's hard to say because they don't do the same thing. FileWriter encodes text to bytes before writing them to a file, using an encoding that depends on the system where you run it, and `DataOutputStream.writeBytes` only writes the lower byte of the two bytes of a `char`. It's possible that `writeBytes` might be fastest since it does a simpler conversion to bytes than `FileWriter` would, and writes only half the compared to `writeChars`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you use `writeChars()` you only output the characters. Be careful, because only the newline character splits the data. Inserting another newline in the middle of a string will likely cause problems. Here is some of the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeChars%28java.lang.String%29) that may be of interest:

> Writes a string to the underlying output stream as a sequence of characters. Each character is written to the data output stream as if by the writeChar method. If no exception is thrown, the counter written is incremented by twice the length of s.